# Numpy.array dtype assignment failure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I am entirely new to numpy and am attempting to create a structured array. My inputs are as follows:

```
data = [2, 0, '1431.033', '436.7573', '170.9705', 0, '', 0]
dt = [('ID', 'int'),
      ('CP', 'int'),
      ('X1', 'float'),
      ('X2', 'float'),
      ('X3', 'float'),
      ('CD', 'int'),
      ('PS', 'str'),
      ('SEID', 'int')]
```

When I attempt to create the array using `np.array(data, dtypes=dt)`, I get the error `{ValueError}invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1431.033'`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm afraid that numpy arrays can not contain different data types in general.

Comment: @NiveshGadipudi, the example for structured arrays shows just that. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays

Comment: `data` must be a tuple or list of tuples.  your's is a list.

Comment: from your doc page: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#assignment-from-python-native-types-tuples

Comment: @josiaLund from the example in the link posted by you its a ndarray of tuples, as stated by other stackoverflow user That is possible but the way you are using is not.

Comment: Thank you both for bringing to my attention that the documentation is using a list of tuples. I though since my list was 1-dimensional, I would be able to feed my values in directly. NumPy's ValueError and message was not all that helpful in helping me to understand what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-and-assignment-to-structured-arrays), The simplest way to assign values to a structured array is using python native tuples. By organizing my data as tuple within list, the structured array can be created successfully.

```
data = [(2, 0, '1431.033', '436.7573', '170.9705', 0, '', 0)]
dt = [('ID', 'int'),
      ('CP', 'int'),
      ('X1', 'float'),
      ('X2', 'float'),
      ('X3', 'float'),
      ('CD', 'int'),
      ('PS', 'str'),
      ('SEID', 'int')]
```